# Extract MEDIA tags from HTML content

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm using `CURL` to get the contents from some web pages. And I need to extract the media tags from the content.

Is there any library available for that? Or any idea on making that would be very great.

Comment: [***SIGH***](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+parse+html)

Comment: Have you put ANY effort into figuring this out yourself? If you can't even try googling for this, then you shouldn't stop by this site either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will this help?

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://example.com/");

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}

echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Keywords: $keywords";
```

Or if you need to save images..

```
$remote_img = 'http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg ';
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_img);
$path = 'images/';
imagejpeg($img, $path);

function save_image($img,$fullpath){
    $ch = curl_init ($img);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        unlink($fullpath);
    }
    $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp); 
}
```

Comment: you can change the TagName to anything you want in order to extract data